# .NET String.Split on EGCs / Text Elements

Tags: .net, f#

String.split "‍‍‍" "" normally results in ["‍"; "‍‍"], breaking up the visual character.

I want a function available that would instead return ["‍‍‍"], not breaking up the visual character. These "visual characters" are referred to as TextElements in the .NET world, or EGCs (extended grapheme clusters) elsewhere, as far as I'm familiar.

Some details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textelementenumerator?view=net-6.0

Here's a bad solution I've made:

```
let ecgStringSplit'
  (elements : string list)
  (sep : string list)
  : string list =
  let startsWithSeparator (str : string list) =
    sep = (str |> List.truncate sep.Length)

  let mutable result = []
  let mutable inProgress = []

  let rec recursiveFn (elementsRemaining : string list) : unit =
    if elementsRemaining = [] then
      result <- result @ [ inProgress |> String.concat "" ]
    elif startsWithSeparator elementsRemaining then
      result <- result @ [ inProgress |> String.concat "" ]
      inProgress <- []
      recursiveFn (List.skip sep.Length elementsRemaining)
    else
      inProgress <- inProgress @ [ elementsRemaining.Head ]
      recursiveFn elementsRemaining.Tail

  recursiveFn elements

  result

let toEgcList (s : string) : string list =
  seq {
    let tee = System.Globalization.StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(s)

    while tee.MoveNext() do
      yield tee.GetTextElement()
  } |> Seq.toList

let ecgStringSplit (str: string) (sep: string) =
  ecgStringSplit' (toEgcList str) (toEgcList sep)

ecgStringSplit "Hello world 1" " " |> printfn "%A" // results in ["Hello"; "world"; "1"]
ecgStringSplit "‍‍‍" "" |> printfn "%A" // results in ["‍‍‍"]
```

Beyond refactoring this to not use mutable values and such, I'm wondering if I'm missing a much simpler solution to this problem?

I'd happily take a C# solution that I can port to F#.

Edit: using something other than F# lists would certainly help perf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A refactored form of the OP

```
let ecgStringSplit str sep =
  let startsWithSeparator str = sep = (str |> List.truncate sep.Length)

  let result = ResizeArray<string>()

  let rec r (strRemaining : List<string>, inProgress) : unit =
    if strRemaining = [] then
      result |> ResizeArray.append (inProgress.ToString())
    elif startsWithSeparator strRemaining then
      result |> ResizeArray.append (inProgress.ToString())

      r (List.skip sep.Length strRemaining, StringBuilder())
    else
      r (strRemaining.Tail, inProgress.Append(strRemaining.Head))

  r (str, StringBuilder())

  result |> ResizeArray.toList
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have the right idea by creating the sequence expression around GetTextElementEnumerator(). This is what I came up with doing a fold, it appears to work (there is some attempt at handling corner cases by filtering out "" in the results).

```
open System.Globalization

let toTextElements s =
    seq {
        let tee = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator s
        while tee.MoveNext() do
            yield tee.GetTextElement()
    }

let split (text, separator) =
    let lastWord, list =
        text
        |> toTextElements
        |> Seq.fold (fun (currentWord, currentList) element ->
            if element = separator then
                "", currentWord::currentList
            else
                currentWord + element, currentList)
            ("", [])
    
    lastWord::list
    |> Seq.filter ((<>) "")
    |> Seq.rev
    |> Seq.toList

split ("Hello world 1", " ") // ["Hello"; "world"; "1"]
split ("‍‍‍‍‍‍", "") // ["‍‍‍"; "‍‍‍"]
split ("‍‍‍", "‍‍‍") // [""; ""]
split (" ", " ") // []
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're able to pass the separator in as-is without having to call `toTextElements` on it. hmm

Comment: The separator you're expecting is just a string, there's no reason to worry about whether it contains EGCs or not, right? It's only the string that you're splitting where you need to worry about that, as the results may be unexpected if you don't take into account the presence of EGCs.

Comment: Ah, I should have included another test case - separators in my case can be of more than 1 character, and your solution fails on inputs like `split("hello llama", "ll")`

Comment: Yes, right. This problem seems to me to be a lot more difficult than I realized at first. Looking around, I found a CodeProject article which references a repo on GitHub, https://github.com/DebugST/STGraphemeSplitter. This is in C#, the code to split is well over 3K lines! The docs are in Chinese, and there is no Nuget package. I think you should try cloning this repo and then calling it from F# should be trivial. Note: I haven't searched past this, there may be other ideas and solutions floating around. For sure this is an esoteric problem.

Comment: For my use case, I ended up going with a refactored form of my OP, which I'm happy enough with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72918775/833921